# Making an electrical circuit

Tags: circuitikz

Is it possible to make an electrical circuit like this?

[image]

I appreciate the help, I'm having trouble with the bus, the circuit breakers and to write the different words an symbols such as the word feeders and the brackets.

Comment: request include your code as an MWE

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Using `circuitikz` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, 
                calligraphy % had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[
BC/.style = {decorate,
    decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm,
    raise=1mm},
    very thick, pen colour=black}
                    ]
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}{\coordinate (n\i) at (0,0.5*\i);}
%
\draw[very thick]   
    (n6) -- (n1);
\draw 
    (n5) to [fuse]  ++ (2,0) -- ++ (3,0) coordinate (aux1)
    (n4) to [fuse]  ++ (2,0) -- ++ (3,0) 
    (n3) to [fuse]  ++ (2,0) -- ++ (3,0) coordinate (aux2)
    (n2) to [fuse]  ++ (2,0) coordinate (aux3)
         to [L]     ++ (2,0) coordinate (aux4) -- (n2 -| aux2)
         node[right] {Capacitor Bus}
    (aux3) to [nos, l=$S_1$]    ++ (0,-2)
           to [cC=$C_1$]         ++ (0,-1)
           node[ground] {}
    (aux4) to [nos, l=$S_2$]    ++ (0,-2)
           to [cC=$C_2$]         ++ (0,-1)
           node[ground] {}
% left
    (n4) to [fuse]  ++ (-2,0)
         to [L, a=$L$, l=Source, mirror] ++ (-2,0)
         node[left, oscillator] {}; 
\draw[BC]   (aux1) -- node[right=3mm] {feeders} (aux2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```